# Swift - How to create an array of string from an object array

Tags: swift, swift2

I have the following class:

```
class ServicePaymentRate : AnyObject {

    var servicePaymentRateUid : String = ""
    var servicePaymentCode : String = ""
    var description : String = ""
    var paymentPercentage : Float = 0
    var isPrimary : Bool = false
    var isFacility : Bool = false

}
```

Then the class is popullated in order to get an array of that class:

```
var rates : Array<ServicePaymentRate>
```

What I need now is to create a String array from the above object array by filtering `description` property. That way I will have a string array that will contain only `description` property values.

> Any clue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let descriptions = rates.map { $0.description }`